# Как сделать раскрывающейся список?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать раскрывающейся список, т.е. допустим есть поле словарь, я на него нажимаю и он раскрывается и становиться видно ключ - значения слов данного словаря
как на этом [сайте](http://www.zakupki.gov.ru/epz/orderplan/plan-graph-card/search-position.html?revision-id=4705995)  раздел *"Дополнительные требования к участникам закупки отдельных видов товаров, работ, услуг"*, только без галочек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь использовать `jQuery`.

### Пример

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="showmenu">Список элементов</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Элемент №1</li>
    <li>Элемент №2</li>
    <li>Элемент №3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! То, что нужно

Comment: @Andrey пожалуйста